# Android TextureView: Video displaying gray frame while calling getBitmap

Tags: android, video, textureview

I am working on android app which can grab frame from video when user performs button click, the android app which is configured to play video using a TextureView. For capturing the frame as a bitmap, i am using:

```
Bitmap bit = textureView.getBitmap(width, height);
```

It works fine, but "getBitmap" takes quite long time (around 150-200 ms for a 640x480 frame). The issue is while getBitmap is being called the a gray frame is getting displayed on the view. This looks like some thing is flicking. Is there a way to get ride of this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the getBitmap method in a separate thread? It would still take some time to get the bitmap, but at least it would not mess with your display callbacks!

Comment: Capture is happening on same thread, it is taking lot of time to capture a frame

Answer (score 0):

You should use Handler to avoid delay time

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Bitmap bit = textureView.getBitmap(width, height);
        //you could save the video frames to use later
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}});
```